# Karma: node-oracledb is not imported well

Tags: node.js, oracle, karma-runner, karma-mocha, node-oracledb

I have [**node-oracledb**](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb) `"oracledb": "1.11.0"` running well in my project, but don't work well in my tests.

#### After `$ npm test` command:

```
15 11 2016 23:29:56.074:ERROR [framework.browserify]: Error: Cannot find
module '../build/Release/oracledb' from 
'/Users/myuser/myproject/node_modules/oracledb/lib'
```

I don't understand what is happen, I need to put something in **karma.conf** file to enable oracledb commonjs dependence?

I'm a little bit lost and any suggestion will be great

*Thank you so much!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your package.json so as not to include oracledb. See the following:
https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/424#issuecomment-224235065